# Bing map - How to use route api in pyspark using dataframe

Tags: pyspark, bing-maps, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the travel time using Bing Route API by passing latitude, longitude coordinates coming from dataframe columns. My code looks like this:

```
def bing_maps(x_lat, x_long, y_lat, y_long):
    try:
        par = {
            'wp.0': ''.join([x_lat, ',', x_long]),
            'wp.1': ''.join([y_lat, ',', y_long]),
            'avoid': 'minimizeTolls',
            'key' : CMEConfig.bingKey } 
        return requests.get(CMEConfig.bingURL, par).json()['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['travelDuration']

    except:
        return 'no_location_available'

udfbing = udf(bing_maps, IntegerType())  

PostalCodeMatrixDistance3 = PostalCodeMatrixDistance2\
    .withColumn('driving_time', udfbing('FromLatitude', 'FromLongitude', 'ToLatitude', 'ToLongitude'))
```

The driving time is calculated in the function, but does not seem to want to hand it over and put in column 'driving_time'. I suspect it has something to do with datatypes, but I cannot figure it out.

When calling the function manually, it seems to work, see example:

```
def bing_maps(x_lat, x_long, y_lat, y_long):
    try:
        par = {
            'wp.0': ''.join([x_lat, ',', x_long]),
            'wp.1': ''.join([y_lat, ',', y_long]),
            'avoid': 'minimizeTolls',
            'key' : CMEConfig.bingKey } 
        res = requests.get(CMEConfig.bingURL, par).json()['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['travelDuration']
        print(res)
        return res
    except:
        return 'no_location_available'

bing_maps('42.843', '-2.6748', '42.6667', '-2.4591')
```

Answer I get back is

```
2742
```

When I call bing_maps without using udf

```
PostalCodeMatrixDistance3 = PostalCodeMatrixDistance2\
    .withColumn('driving_time', bing_maps('FromLatitude', 'FromLongitude', 'ToLatitude', 'ToLongitude'))
```

I get this errror:

```
col should be Column
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1501, in withColumn
    assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Your help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Not sure about your python code, but wanted to point out the Bing Maps has a distance matrix service which you should use if you only need travel time/distance. It would be a lot faster and a much smaller response size: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt827298.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated your code and it seems to work fine, which leads me to believe the error is with the datatypes of your dataframe.

Your `bing_maps` function will call `''.join([x_lat, ',', x_long]),`, which silently assumes that the arguments of the iterable (the list in this case) are all strings. That's why calling it manually (without using the user defined function, udf) works.

If the `'FromLatitude', 'FromLongitude', 'ToLatitude', 'ToLongitude'` columns in your dataframe are not of the `StringType`, but e.g. the `DoubleType`, then calling the `udfbing` will result in a Python TypeError `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

One way to solve that (and at the same time allow floats which are cast as strings) is to change how the data gets joined. Consider e.g. changing

```
'wp.0': ''.join([x_lat, ',', x_long]),
```

to

```
'wp.0': "{lat1},{long1}".format(lat1=x_lat, long1=x_long),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oliver your answer helped a lot to put me on right track. 
It's not the input parameters that caused the problem however I have enhanced the code as suggested, but the driving time as output.
I defined it as integer, but somehow the dataframe wanted it back as string.

So I changed only this statement and it worked:

```
udfbing = udf(bing_maps, StringType())
```

Comment: would you happen to share the URL you use for this call?